# Setting up custom AuthenticationScheme when using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm attempting to write a custom authentication/authorization for my mvc 6 asp.net 5 web app.  I've written custom policies and requirements using

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler 
Microsoft`.AspNet.Authorization.IAuthorizationRequirement
```

and I can trace through the code and it seems to be working as expected.  If the user matches the requirement and I do a context.Succeeded(requirement) and return.  However if the user doesn't match and I do a context.Fail() I want it to redirect to a cshtml page that displays a "You are unauthorized for this feature".  Instead it comes up with a blank web page.  When I check the consul I can see that the code returned a 403 Forbidden error.  So I need to know how to redirect it to the page.  I have tried adding to my authorize attribute:

`enter code here`[Authorize(Policy = "xyz", ActiveAuthenticationScheme = "Cookie")]

but when I do this it always redirects to "/account/Login" even when the user is authenticated.  I've tried to setup in my ConfigureServices of my startup.cs

```
 services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie";
                o.LoginPath = "";
                o.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Home/Unauthorized/");
                o.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            });
```

but it seems to be ignoring the settings.  I change the scheme to something more generic like "Manpower" then I get a "No authentication Handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme" error when the user doesn't have authorization.  I'm using windows authentication.  I've also tried in the Configure method of my startup.cs the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
options.AuthenticationScheme = "Manpower";
options.LoginPath = "";
options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Home/Unauthorized/");
options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
});
```

The later doesn't generate an error, but causes the same behavior in which all requests are redirected to /account/login even if they are authorized.  All help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is you're mixing cookie auth and Windows auth. You don't need both.

Remove the cookie authentication pieces, then remove the  `ActiveAuthenticationScheme = "Cookie"` from your policy. The policy you created requires a cookie, but as Windows Authentication doesn't use cookies you will always get an unauthorized response.

There are a couple of things to note though. Windows Auth only supports role based authentication and it's broken in RC1. A fix will be in RC2.

Comment: Is there any way to mix windows and cookie auth such that if windows authentication fails you can allow the user to login and use a cookie to authenticate?